# Require simplification of Batch Script for lesser memory utilization

Tags: batch-file

I have a Batch script which starts a Launcher file and waits for all sub programs loads and check for Chrome Browser is closed if "Yes" then it closes all the other programs form the process.

if Chrome Browser is not closed it loops through until it is closed.

The problem found is it used find command in loops thus causing much memory usage.
(I have found few "Find" and "Tasklist" commands which are running under CMD.exe) attached screenshot.[image]. this was found based on process explorer
Can any one please suggest me to use the same code in simplest way thus making it use less memory. thanks in advance.

**Purpose** 
(i have opted php-desktop of (Chromium) version for custom programming of php files. When (Browser) is Closed all the other PHP and Portable Chromium files were left unclosed in task-list. For this i thought of running a batch program where it starts checking the browser status and once it is closed all the other sub programs were  closed forcibly.)

```
        @echo off
        SETLOCAL

    REM Main FILE to be loded and wait for 25 Sec so that sub programs will load
        start Launcher.exe
        timeout /t 25 /nobreak > NUL

    REM Check Browser is closed if closed then goes to ITSOut if not runs untill its closed

        :MAIN
        tasklist | FIND "Chrome.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Chrome.exe">NUL
        if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" GOTO :MAIN
        if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" GOTO :ITSout

    REM Checks browser is still open (exists) after confirming it closes sub programs 
        :ITSout
        tasklist | FIND "Chrome.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Chrome.exe">NUL
        if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" GOTO :MAIN

        FOR /f "tokens=2" %%i IN (
                       ' tasklist ^| find "ChromiumPortable.exe" '
            ) DO SET pid=%%i
            IF DEFINED pid (
                REM ECHO TASKKILL /pid %pid% /T
                TASKKILL /pid %pid% /F /T
            ) ELSE (GOTO :MAIN)


        tasklist | FIND "Chrome.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Chrome.exe">NUL
        if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" GOTO :MAIN

        REM echo "SETLOCAL top line phpdesktop.exe is here"
        FOR /f "tokens=2" %%i IN (
            ' tasklist ^| find "phpdesktop.exe" '
            ) DO SET pid=%%i
            IF DEFINED pid (
                REM ECHO TASKKILL /pid %pid% /T
                TASKKILL /pid %pid% /F /T
            ) ELSE (GOTO :MAIN)

     GOTO eof
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have in this code is high CPU utilisation

```
REM Check Browser is closed if closed then goes to ITSOut if not runs untill its closed

    :MAIN
    tasklist | FIND "Chrome.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Chrome.exe">NUL
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" GOTO :MAIN
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" GOTO :ITSout
```

It might be better to use this - and the timeout will lower the CPU usage.

```
    :MAIN
    tasklist | FINDSTR /i "^Chrome.exe" >NUL 
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" timeout 6 >nul & GOTO :MAIN
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" GOTO :ITSout
```

Comment: this seems to be working like a charm but, any other alternatives  to reduce frequency of using switches / GOTO / IF checks several times ?

Answer (score 0):

Which tool do you use to recognize that memory problem is in FIND utility? Is everothing correct, except memory usage?

I can't check FIND right now, but I found, that following code does not spend too much memory:

```
:MAIN
tasklist | grep chrome
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" GOTO :MAIN
```

(here I use GREP instead of FIND, because grep is more powerful tool; May be it is solution for you)

Also I can't understand logic in your code (it looks like you have infinite loop, but you have not told us about this problem).

Comment: Every thing seems to be perfectly working, the major concern is that (As said) that loop of checking the browser will be under process until user closes the browser. So, is there any way to simplify the loop and used other conditions which minimizes the check process i.e (find and tasklist) process.

Answer (score 0):

Your program flow (logic) makes no sense to me. But I believe the following should give the nearly the same result. The only difference is the following code will attempt to kill all ChromiumPortable.exe and phpdesktop.exe, whereas your original only kills one per loop.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

start Launcher.exe
timeout /t 25 /nobreak > NUL

:MAIN
for /f "skip=2" %%A in (
  'tasklist /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe"'
) do (timeout 1 /nobreak >null & goto :MAIN)

set "found="
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2" %%A in (
  'tasklist /fi "imagename eq ChromiumPortable.exe"'
) do ( set found=1 & taskkill /pid %%A /f /t )
if not defined found goto :MAIN

for /f "skip=2" %%A in (
  'tasklist /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe"'
) do goto :MAIN

set "found="
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2" %%A in (
  'tasklist /fi "imagename eq phpdesktop.exe"'
) do (set found=1 & taskkill /pid %%A /f /t)
if not defined found goto :MAIN

REM I have no idea what this is
eout 555

exit /b
```

But the logic of the overall script seems wrong to me. Why repeated check for chrome.exe? Why loop if ChromiumPortable.exe or phpdesktop.exe not found? It might never end.

I think the following makes more sense:

```
@echo off

start Launcher.exe
timeout /t 25 /nobreak > NUL

:wait
for /f "skip=2" %%A in (
  'tasklist /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe"'
) do (timeout 1 /nobreak >null & goto :wait)

for /f "skip=2 tokens=2" %%A in (
  'tasklist /fi "imagename eq ChromiumPortable.exe"'
) do taskkill /pid %%A /f /t

for /f "skip=2 tokens=2" %%A in (
  'tasklist /fi "imagename eq phpdesktop.exe"'
) do taskkill /pid %%A /f /t

REM I have no idea what this is
eout 555

exit /b
```

Comment: The used of Find was done because this should be case sensitive i.e chrome.exe is of Google chrome version and I use Chromium portable version. In tasklist it is shows as "Chrome.exe". is there any way to check case sensitive as said above. I have tried replacing /fl "imagename ... with find as it was in my above script but failed to work. I have observed that it(batch program) has exited after timeout 25.

Comment: @Jimson - Case in Windows file names if for display only. Case is ignored by Windows when comparing file names. I don't see why you think you need a case sensitive search, unless perhaps you are using a shared Unix file system that is case sensitive.

Comment: As said, when a users uses Google chrome (chrome.exe) for his routine task and as well as Chromium portable (Chrome.exe) (the actual inbuilt browser is Chromium portable) Tasklist images name shown are same except when checked with Case "find" command. Even before this comment i have tried with tasklist and found that both are shown in the list. And i dont want my batch program to distrub  and closed users chrome browser.